# Error while reading from command prompt using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, processbuilder

I'm having an issue while executing the java code by using ProcessBuilder.

Below are the scenarios of the code where i have been facing the error.

**Scenario-1**

```
String[] commands = {"cd C:\\glm","glm"};

    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = rt.exec(commands);

    InputStream stdin = proc.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stdin);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    String line = null;
    System.out.println("<OUTPUT>");

    while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
         System.out.println(line);
```

the ***error*** after executing the code is

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cd C:\glm": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:485)
    at com.glm.GLM_Command.main(GLM_Command.java:15)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:385)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:136)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
```

after the above code, i tried with the following code

**Scenario-2**

```
File thisFile = new File("C:\\somefile.txt");
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\glm\\glm.exe");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        pb.redirectError(thisFile);
        pb.start();
```

the output for the above code is as shown in the image

[image]

**Scenario-3**

the tricky part is while executing the command through command prompt:

the output is as displayed in the below image

[image]

My task is to read the data which is in the command prompt.

Finally

**Scenario-4**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\glm\\glm");
        // Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c dir");
        inheritIO(p.getInputStream(), System.out);
        inheritIO(p.getErrorStream(), System.err);

    }

    private static void inheritIO(final InputStream src, final PrintStream dest) 
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(src);
                while (sc.hasNextLine()) 
                {
                    dest.println(sc.nextLine());
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

the output is shown below

[image]

please suggest me where i was wrong.

Note: we have been providing the command from the manual :) .
(if there is no other solution for this, is there any way to read all the values before getting the error in a file for workaround?).

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, really. Is your problem that you can't run the command at all? Or is it that you only see the error but not the other lines of output? In each of your scenarios, what is the problem that bothers you and what is the output that you expect?

Comment: The expected output is displayed in the "Scenario-3", which ran manually through command prompt and that is working fine. If i try to retrieve through java code it is throwing the above errors.

Comment: So the Java programs only display the error message and not the output? Is that your problem? But you are displaying a dialog box, not something that looks like `System.out` output. Where is the actual `System.out` output going?

Comment: @RealSkeptic the output for the "Scenario-4" in the console is EMPTY, and finally ended up with the dialog box.

Comment: My guess is that the GLM program detects the fact that it is not being run through a command-line, and therefore it works in GUI mode instead of using stdin/stdout, and that's why it displays its own dialog instead of just printing the error.